# Algorithm with O(n) time and O(n) space to compare two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

A and B are two arrays with n elements each in the range 1 to n^2.

1.How to check if the elements of A are distinct in O(n) time and O(n) space

2.How to check if A and B have a common element in O(n) time and O(n) space.

Both the algorithms shouldn't use Hash sets or any other advanced data structure. A and B are just simple Arrays.

Comment: Theoritically, q1 is called element uniqueness problem which is proved to have a lower bound of O(nlogn). But there is condition that number does not cross n^2

Answer (score 0):

Both operations are easy to do in linear time if the arrays are sorted. The bound of n^2 allows a linear-time radix sort (radix n).

Comment: The arrays are not assumed to be sorted. What is the solution in that case?

Comment: @Malgorythm Sort them in linear time and space with radix sort.

Comment: So you mean to say, first sort them in O(n) time and space. Then use comparision after that. But wont that comparision take O(nlogn) extra atleast?

Comment: @Malgorythm No.

Comment: I understood the comparision. Can you explain this "The bound of n^2 allows a linear-time radix sort."

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two **sorted** arrays in O(n) time in merge-like manner.

But it is possible to sort arrays with given limitations in O(n)? Yes, it is. 
Cormen et al algorithmic course contains assignment about such sorting (integer array in n^2 range) in the end chapter devoted to radix/digit sorting.

Question looks like homework, so I think this clue is enough.

Comment: It is not a homework. I want to solve some bigger problem and here I am stuck with this small part. I am struggling to sort that array in O(n) given the limitation on range of elements. Could you please provide some insight?

Comment: @Malgorythm If it's not homework, then why not use a hash set or similar?

Comment: Consider radix sort with base=n (in this numeral system your numbers have at most two digits)